# Using Combine with UISearchController and searchBar text change event

Tags: swift, combine

I have a function that setups `UISearchController` within `ViewController`.
I'm trying to subscribe to events from `searchBar.text` property and `debounce` events as this is making network calls (and I want to make as less as possible).
Unfortunately the sink is only called once when `setupSearchController` is called. What did I wrong?

```
private func setupSearchController() {
    let powerSearchResultViewController = PowerSearchResultViewController(coreDataManager: self.coreDataManager)
    let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: powerSearchResultViewController)
    searchController.searchBar.autocapitalizationType = .none
    let defaultAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor(white: 1.0, alpha: 0.8)]
    UITextField.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]).defaultTextAttributes = defaultAttributes
    searchController.searchBar.publisher(for: \.text)
        .debounce(for: .seconds(1), scheduler: DispatchQueue.main)
        .sink { [weak self] value in
            guard let self = self, let value = value, value != "" else { return }
            self.powerSearchResultViewController?.performQuery(with: value)
        }
        .store(in: &self.disposables)
    searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
    searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search..."
    searchController.delegate = self
    self.navigationItem.searchController = searchController
    self.navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false
    self.powerSearchResultViewController = powerSearchResultViewController
    self.searchController = searchController
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: 
UISearchTextField.textDidChangeNotification, 
object: searchController.searchBar.searchTextField)
            .map {
                ($0.object as! UISearchTextField).text
            }
            .sink { [weak self] value in
                guard let self = self, let value = value, value != "" else { return }
            self.powerSearchResultViewController?.performQuery(with: value)
            }
            .store(in: &cancellable)
```

Based on this answer: [Somehow combine with search controller not working, any idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60241335/somehow-combine-with-search-controller-not-working-any-idea)